# draw function in scikit-geometry fails to display

Tags: python, scikits

i'm getting started with scikit-geometry and am trying to reproduce some of the examples, but the plot function doesn't work as expected.

i'm working in VSCode and managing my environment with Anaconda on Windows 10.

i'm just reading through the samples in the [notebook](https://github.com/scikit-geometry/scikit-geometry/blob/master/notebooks/draw_examples.ipynb).  the snippet runs, but no graphic is displayed.

```
import skgeom
from skgeom.draw import draw

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import math

a = skgeom.Point2(4, 5)

print('a:', a)

draw(a, color='purple')
```

the docs indicate that the draw function is built from the matplotlib plot function, but it doesn't support the .show() method, so i'm not really sure what i'm doing wrong.

suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this is what you are *supposed* to do, but adding a call to `plt.show()` at the end worked for me.

```
import skgeom
from skgeom.draw import draw

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

import math

a = skgeom.Point2(4, 5)

print('a:', a)

draw(a, color='purple')

plt.show()
```